# Use correct offset when binding a buffer to a memory

Tags: vulkan

I have a big chunk of device memory and multiple uniform buffers which I want to bind. Obviously, I need an offset. Let's see what the documentation for `vkBindBufferMemory` says:

> `memoryOffset` is the start offset of the region of memory which is to
>   be bound to the buffer...
>
> `memoryOffset` must be an integer multiple of the `alignment` member of
>   the `VkMemoryRequirements` structure returned from a call to
>   `vkGetBufferMemoryRequirements` with buffer

Ok, that's clear - I have multiple uniform buffers created with the same flags so I can use the same alignment for all of them. But wait, there's another usage note for `vkBindBufferMemory` in specs:

> If buffer was created with the `VK_BUFFER_USAGE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_BIT`,
>   `memoryOffset` must be a multiple of
>   `VkPhysicalDeviceLimits::minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment`

That's confuing. Can I safely use `VkPhysicalDeviceLimits::minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment` for my case or should I compare it with `VkMemoryRequirements::alignment` and choose the lowest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, a quick note: if You want to compare `VkPhysicalDeviceLimits::minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment` with `VkMemoryRequirements::alignment` then You should choose the largest of these two values, not the lowest (smallest) value.

But in the spec we can also read:

> The implementation guarantees certain properties about the memory
>   requirements returned by `vkGetBufferMemoryRequirements` and
>   `vkGetImageMemoryRequirements`:
>
> - The alignment member is identical for all `VkBuffer` objects created with the same combination of values for the `usage` and `flags` members in the `VkBufferCreateInfo` structure passed to `vkCreateBuffer`.
> - The alignment member satisfies the buffer descriptor offset alignment requirements associated with the `VkBuffer`’s `usage`:
>
>   - If usage included `VK_BUFFER_USAGE_UNIFORM_TEXEL_BUFFER_BIT` or `VK_BUFFER_USAGE_STORAGE_TEXEL_BUFFER_BIT`, `alignment` must be an integer multiple of `VkPhysicalDeviceLimits::minTexelBufferOffsetAlignment`.
>   - **If usage included `VK_BUFFER_USAGE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_BIT`, `alignment` must be an integer multiple of `VkPhysicalDeviceLimits::minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment`.**
>   - If usage included `VK_BUFFER_USAGE_STORAGE_BUFFER_BIT`, `alignment` must be an integer multiple of `VkPhysicalDeviceLimits::minStorageBufferOffsetAlignment`.

So You don't have to compare them but only take the (multiple of the) alignment value returned by the `vkGetBufferMemoryRequirements()` function in the `VkMemoryRequirements` structure.

Based on the above information, I think that `VkPhysicalDeviceLimits::minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment` value is more important when using dynamic uniform buffers as the offset value provided during the `vkCmdBindDescriptorSets()` function call must also be a multiple of the above value.

Comment: Thank you. I missed that part of the documentation. Another benefit of `minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment` is that it can reduce a total size of the memory. For example, if I need 16 floats in one buffer, but the `VkMemoryRequirements::alignment` returns 256 it's clearly a waste of space. And if `minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment` is less it should be selected (that what I mean when I wrote about lowest value).

Comment: FWIW, the language about `VkMemoryRequirements::alignment` being an integer multiple of the various `min*BufferOffsetAlignment` values was only added in spec version v1.1.77 (~5 weeks ago), so it might not have been there in the version you looked at originally. But it was always the intent and there have been conformance tests for it for a long time, so you should be able to rely on it.

Comment: Also, it's not safe to bind to `minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment` if it's less than `VkMemoryRequirements::alignment`. You have to respect the required alignment when binding the VkBuffer to VkDeviceMemory, there may be other constraints than just the minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment. *But* you could align to only `minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment` when using non-zero dynamic offsets; `VkMemoryRequirements::alignment` only applies to the buffer/memory binding offset, while `minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment` applies to descriptor offsets.